# Unable to run multiple bluetooth connection

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

this the main activity java file of my code

```
package com.ramimartin.sample.multibluetooth;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.ramimartin.multibluetooth.activity.BluetoothFragmentActivity;
import com.ramimartin.multibluetooth.bluetooth.mananger.BluetoothManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import butterknife.OnClick;


public class MainActivity extends BluetoothFragmentActivity implements DiscoveredDialogFragment.DiscoveredDialogListener {

    @InjectView(R.id.listview)
    ListView mListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    List<String> mListLog;

    @InjectView(R.id.communication)
    EditText mEditText;
    @InjectView(R.id.send)
    ImageButton mSendBtn;

    @InjectView(R.id.client)
    ToggleButton mClientToggleBtn;
    @InjectView(R.id.serveur)
    ToggleButton mServerToggleBtn;

    @InjectView(R.id.connect)
    Button mConnectBtn;
    @InjectView(R.id.disconnect)
    Button mDisconnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mListLog = new ArrayList<String>();
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_console, mListLog);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int myNbrClientMax() {
        return 7;
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.serveur)
    public void serverType() {
        setLogText("===> Start Server ! Your mac address : " + mBluetoothManager.getYourBtMacAddress());
        setTimeDiscoverable(BluetoothManager.BLUETOOTH_TIME_DICOVERY_3600_SEC);
        selectServerMode();
        mServerToggleBtn.setChecked(true);
        mClientToggleBtn.setChecked(false);
        mConnectBtn.setEnabled(true);
        mConnectBtn.setText("Scan Devices");
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.client)
    public void clientType() {
        setLogText("===> Start Client ! Your mac address : " + mBluetoothManager.getYourBtMacAddress());
        setTimeDiscoverable(BluetoothManager.BLUETOOTH_TIME_DICOVERY_120_SEC);
        selectClientMode();
        mServerToggleBtn.setChecked(false);
        mClientToggleBtn.setChecked(true);
        mConnectBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.connect)
    public void connect() {
        setLogText("===> Start Scanning devices ...");
        if (getTypeBluetooth() == BluetoothManager.TypeBluetooth.Client) {
            showDiscoveredDevicesDialog();
        }
        scanAllBluetoothDevice();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.disconnect)
    public void disconnect() {
        setLogText("===> Disconnect");
        disconnectClient();
        disconnectServer();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.send)
    public void send() {
        if (isConnected()) {
            sendMessage(mEditText.getText().toString());
            setLogText("===> Send : " + mEditText.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothStartDiscovery() {
        setLogText("===> Start discovering ! Your mac address : " + mBluetoothManager.getYourBtMacAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothDeviceFound(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if(getTypeBluetooth() == BluetoothManager.TypeBluetooth.Server) {
            setLogText("===> Device detected and Thread Server created for this address : " + device.getAddress());
        }else{
            setLogText("===> Device detected : "+ device.getAddress());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientConnectionSuccess() {
        setLogText("===> Client Connexion success !");
        mEditText.setText("Client");
        mSendBtn.setEnabled(true);
        mConnectBtn.setEnabled(false);
        mDisconnect.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientConnectionFail() {
        setLogText("===> Client Connexion fail !");
        mServerToggleBtn.setChecked(false);
        mClientToggleBtn.setChecked(false);
        mDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
        mConnectBtn.setEnabled(false);
        mConnectBtn.setText("Connect");
        mEditText.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServeurConnectionSuccess() {
        setLogText("===> Serveur Connexion success !");
        mEditText.setText("Server");
        mDisconnect.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServeurConnectionFail() {
        setLogText("===> Serveur Connexion fail !");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothCommunicator(String messageReceive) {
        setLogText("===> receive msg : " + messageReceive);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothNotAviable() {
        setLogText("===> Bluetooth not aviable on this device");
        mSendBtn.setEnabled(false);
        mClientToggleBtn.setEnabled(false);
        mServerToggleBtn.setEnabled(false);
        mConnectBtn.setEnabled(false);
        mDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void setLogText(String text) {
        mListLog.add(text);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setSelection(mListView.getCount() - 1);
    }

    private void showDiscoveredDevicesDialog() {
        String tag = DiscoveredDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();
        DiscoveredDialogFragment fragment = DiscoveredDialogFragment.newInstance();
        fragment.setListener(this);
        showDialogFragment(fragment, tag);
    }

    private void showDialogFragment(DialogFragment dialogFragment, String tag) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(dialogFragment, tag);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceSelectedForConnection(String addressMac) {
        setLogText("===> Connect to " + addressMac);
        createClient(addressMac);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanClicked() {
        scanAllBluetoothDevice();
    }
}

****************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

here is layout of the application

stackoverflow does not allow me to ask question , i am beginner , very tough to ask  question plz try to find out error 
ur response will be appreciated

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/rami_logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/communication"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/communication"
        android:layout_above="@+id/connexion"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_above="@+id/connexion"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/communication"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/send"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/connexion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/connect"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/client"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="Client"
            android:textOn="Client"/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/serveur"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="Serveur"
            android:textOn="Serveur"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/disconnect"
        android:text="Connect"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disconnect"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Disconnect"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnoAB.jpg)[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aympf.jpg)

Comment: You can copy and paste the error log